# Microsoft Report Viewer 15 does not display external images and gives an error 404 on Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-config, reportviewer

I have developed an RDLC report viewer web application using asp.net, vb.net, SQL procedures, and datasets. The report includes text, values, and images (external images). Executed the application and then display data, except external images and the following error.

[Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGury.png)

Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd is registered in web.config correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
          <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="constr" connectionString="Data Source=SHO-AAAAAAA-LAP;Initial Catalog=XXXXXERP;Timeout=600;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
    </handlers>
       <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845DCD8080CC91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-16.0.0.0" newVersion="16.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>     
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>  
</configuration>
```

ASPX

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Store/store.Master" CodeBehind="PO_Print.aspx.vb" Inherits="sathuta_erp.PO_Print" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">    
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">  

    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Width="100%">
        <LocalReport EnableExternalImages="true"></LocalReport>
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
                            
</asp:Content>
```

VB

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Configuration
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms
Imports System.IO

Public Class PO_Print
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim connSTORE As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constrINVDB").ConnectionString)
    
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        PageAllow()
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            If Request.QueryString("PoHeaderID") Is Nothing Then
                Response.Redirect("~/Store/PO_Header.aspx")
            Else
                PrintPage()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
   
    Private Sub PrintPage()
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Store/ASST/RDLC/PoPrint.rdlc")
        Dim DsPoItems1 As DsPoItems = GetDataPoItems()
        Dim DsPoHeader1 As DsPoHeader = GetDataPoHeader()
        Dim datasourcePoItems As New ReportDataSource("DsPoItems", DsPoItems1.Tables(0))
        Dim datasourcePoHeader As New ReportDataSource("DsPoHeader", DsPoHeader1.Tables(0))
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasourcePoItems)
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasourcePoHeader)
    End Sub
    
    Private Function GetDataPoHeader() As DsPoHeader
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("PO_Header_PoHeaderID", connSTORE)
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                cmd.Connection = connSTORE
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PoHeaderID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Request.QueryString("PoHeaderID")

                connSTORE.Open()
                connSTORE.Close()

                Using DsPoHeader1 As New DsPoHeader()
                    sda.Fill(DsPoHeader1, "DataTable1")
                    Return DsPoHeader1
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function
    
    Private Function GetDataPoItems() As DsPoItems
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("PO_Items_PoHeaderID", connSTORE)
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                cmd.Connection = connSTORE
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PoHeaderID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Request.QueryString("PoHeaderID")

                connSTORE.Open()
                connSTORE.Close()

                Using DsPoItems1 As New DsPoItems()
                    sda.Fill(DsPoItems1, "DataTable1")
                    Return DsPoItems1
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function    

End Class
```

Please review my above code and give me a suggestion to fix the above error and display external images in the report viewer.

Thanking you, samsmuthu

uninstall and reinstall Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms from nuget